# Concurrent Key Value Table

Tags: sql, database

I have these tables:

`CO_KEYVALUE`:

```
co_keyvalueid int
co_keyid int
value text
```

`CO_KEY`:

```
co_keyid int
keyname varchar(128)
```

The problem is: how to control efficiently the field keyname to be unique in the application layer?

For example:

**Client 1** inserts ("Name", "Client 1")

At the same time, client 2 inserts ("Name", "Client 1")

```
Function Put(Name, Value) {
    Id = SELECT co_keyid FROM co_key WHERE co_keyname = :Name

    If(!Id) {
       // Autoincrement
       Id = INSERT INTO co_key (NULL, :Name)
    }

    INSERT INTO co_keyvalue (NULL, :id, :Value)
}
```

I know I can lock all table, but there is any other way?

Comment: Which database? If you define them as UNIQUE the DB should handle this.

Answer (score 1):

You do not solve this problem in the application layer.  You solve it in the database layer.  As a general rule, you want the database to enforce the rules for data integrity, for precisely the reason you note -- multiple threads may attempt incompatible operations at the same time.  Databases are ACID-compliant (or at least *can* be with the right parameter settings), allowing for isolation of different transactions.

So, the solution to your problem is pair of unique constraint/indexes: `co_key(keyname)` and `co_keyvalue(co_keyid, value)`.  Once you have these in place, you will need to check for errors in your code that are generated by improper data.

Comment: Right... So I have to check for error in: INSERT INTO co_key (NULL, :Name) and if it throws "unique violation" I have to performe any "SELECT" again in the table?

Comment: @user3558040 . . . I would probably do it in the other order.  Look for the id and if it doesn't exist, insert it and then use `last_insert_id()`.

Comment: This is not what I'm doing?

Comment: @user3558040 . . . That is what the code in the question is basically doing.  I was referring to the comment.